# Python & Django, UUID not unique

Tags: django, uuid

I'm developing an application using Django. I have a form in which the user uploads 3 different files (at least one). Then those files are sended to a home script that generates some result files. I want to store all those files in one directory, each directory name unique by form submission. I've look around on the Internet and I find the UUID technology. I installed the module of Django named django-uuid-upload-path. But when I submit my form, it is always the same uuid that is returned, looking like a UUID string. Here is my model where I'm using this module :

```
from django.db import models
from uuid_upload_path import uuid
class Analysis(models.Model):
    uidDir = uuid()
    dirFile = 'documents/%Y/%m/%d/' + str(uidDir)
    structureFile = models.FileField(upload_to = dirFile)
```

I've tried to use upload_to from this module in this way :

from uuid_upload_path import upload_to
   class Analysis(models.Model):
      structureFile = models.FileFiels(upload_to = upload_to)

I've done this for my 3 FileFields and it gave me 3 different UUID on one form submission. The problem is now that my files are not in the same directory.

Here is my controller, where I upload the files submitted by the user :

```
def analysis(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        documents = Analysis.objects.all()
        form = AnalysisForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Analysis(structureFile = request.FILES['structureFile'])
            newdoc.save()
```

I've tried with the uuid module from Python but I got the same problem. I've tried to refresh the web page and to delete the cookies but nothing worked.

P.S : I'm using Safari on OS X 10.9.4.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you make a class variable equal to `uuid()`, the function will run only *once*, when the module is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should't hardcode your UUID in model section. Django ORM will use it once while creating database.

In your model you should keep field with UUID, but this UUID should be generated in views.py while uploading files.

So there are steps, how upload should look like:

1. You feel in form and send it.
2. Your controller gets the form with data.
3. In your controller you generate UUID
4. Your controller saves data in database (and there you should store path to files along with generated UUIDs)

Comment: Have you an idea on how can I do the last step ? I don't know how to get the value of the UUID field of my model and to give it to my file field ?

Answer (score 0):

From the `upload_to` documentation :

> **This may also be a callable, such as a function**, which will be called
>   to obtain the upload path, including the filename. This callable must
>   be able to accept two arguments, and return a Unix-style path (with
>   forward slashes) to be passed along to the storage system. The two
>   arguments that will be passed are:

What you need to do is create this uuid function and pass it to `upload_to`.

Comment: As I have 3 uploaded files, won't i have the same problem as previously with 3 different directories ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on the mailing list of Django. Here is how you get the value of a field :

```
def dir_file(analysis, file_name):  # should live outside your model
    return 'documents/%s/%s' % ( analysis.uuidDir, file_name)
```

In the model, you put :

```
uuidDir = models.CharField(max_length = 36)
structureFile = models.FileField(upload_to = dir_file)
```

Now my directory are UUID and generated at each form submission !